# How does the Xenon Discord bot chatlog command work?

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

I'm asking about [this Discord bot](https://xenon.bot), Xenon Bot. It claims to have the ability to backup messages. How does a Discord bot backup messages...? It can't just send messages as any user. Does it create a Webhook to send the messages? I'm mildly interested here.

Comment: Yes, discord webhooks can be configured to have an avatar and name of your choice.
You'd only need one webhook registered to a channel to 'recreate' the chat logs, the mentioned bot appears to merely create a 'copy' of messages that can be fetched from the channel history.  Like every other operation webhooks have their own rate-limits that you should adhere to when sending messages through them.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the response! That makes sense.